# Edit listView content - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, textview, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom `ArrayAdapter` set to a `listView`. Inside each element of the `listView` I have an item that matches a .xml I created. Codes shown below:

**listContent.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
[... some code ommited]
    <ImageView
    [...]
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/listViewText"
    [...]
```

**Custom Array Adapter getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)**

```
if (position < 4)
{
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listContent,null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listViewText);

    tv.setTextSize(18);
    if (position == 0) tv.setText("0");
    else if (position == 1) tv.setText("1");
    else if (position == 2) tv.setText("2");
    else if (position == 3) tv.setText("3");

    return convertView;
}
return null;
```

I can't seem to get this to work, I always get some error. What do I need to do in order to edit the `TextView` inside my listView item?

Comment: define 'some error', and post relevant stacktrace. Plus, use convertView.findById, as findById is not defined for an ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Custom Array Adapter getView code as:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

 View row = convertView;

 if(row==null){
  LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
  row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listContent, parent, false);
 }

 TextView tv=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listViewText);


tv.setTextSize(18);
    if (position == 0) tv.setText("0");
    else if (position == 1) tv.setText("1");
    else if (position == 2) tv.setText("2");
    else if (position == 3) tv.setText("3");

 return row;
}
```

Comment: @njzk2 : just  mistake in changing  code according to user code

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listViewText);
```

to

```
TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewText);
```

and remove this

```
if (position < 4)
```

Comment: Finding the ID from `convertView` worked. The `(position<4)` refers to something else not relevant in this case but I need it there. :P

Comment: if your getView will have this line if (position < 4) and if your listView will have more than 4 items you will have NullPointerException, because convertView can not be NULL.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but for now I only have 4 items in my list (it is static) and later I'll add more items but they will be different from the ones above, so that's the `if`.